# Pixelated text in UILabel within UIScrollView, both with transparent background

Tags: ios, ios5, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a weird issue:

I have a UIScrollView whose background is transparent. Inside of it there are a few UILabels also with a transparent background and with a custom font.

When the scrollview is first displayed everything looks sharp and good but as soon as I start panning the scroll view, the text of the labels gets extremely pixelated.

This does not happen if i set an opaque background to the labels.

Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I've been having a similar issue. I have tried using stock fonts and custom fonts but below about 18 font size the fonts that fit our theme look pixalated...

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you may be adding several layers of the identical `UILabel` on top of the others on scroll. Place a debug breakpoint on the code that adds it to your content, and ensure it is only being called once.

The "pixelation" could be caused by the overlapping of anti-aliasing pixels.