# Pixelated UILabel in table cell

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview, uilabel

To add a **UILabel** to a table cell I use

```
UILabel *timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 10, 40, 12)];
timeLabel.text = @"2s";
timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
timeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
timeLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
timeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
timeLabel.frame = CGRectIntegral(timeLabel.frame);
[cell.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];
```

in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

This works fine until I scroll the table or select a cell. Then the label becomes pixelated.

At load: [image]

after action: [image]

I also tried to add the label by subclassing **UITableViewCell** and load it in 
`- (void) layoutSubviews`.

I already found related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383205/pixelated-text-in-uilabel-within-uiscrollview-both-with-transparent-background) and [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1161-over-anti-aliasing-in-uilabel.html) but nothing worked.

**EDIT: It's not possible to use the standard cell labels since they're already in use. I need to add an additional label.**

Comment: What version of iOS are you on? If it's 6.x, it could be a bug in the software (it could even be a bug if you're not on 5.x…nobody's perfect). Is it possible to make the background not transparent?

Comment: I tested it on iOS 5.1.1 and iOS 6b4. I can't imagine it's a bug since many apps including Facebook and Twitter add UILabels to a table cell.

Comment: yes it's possible to make the background not transparent but this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working with a dirty fix.

In **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

I set

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`.

In a subclass of **UITableViewCell** I load the timeLabel in **initWithStyle** as follows:

```
timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(270, 10, 40, 12)];
timeLabel.text = @"2s";
timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
timeLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
timeLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
timeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
[self.contentView addSubview:timeLabel];
```

then I override these two functions:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(highlighted == YES){
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBg@2x.png"];
        //scale custom cell background to necessary height
        UIImage *scaledImage = [image scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(1,self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        //set cell background
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledImage];
        //set textcolor for default labels
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        //set textcolor for custom label
        timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
        //cope background for custom label background since timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] doesnt work
        CGImageRef ref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(scaledImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 10, 12, 20));
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
        //set custom label background
        timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
    } else {
        //set unselected colors
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x808080);
        timeLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x808080);
        //white background works without the label pixelates
        timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(selected == YES){
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBg@2x.png"];
        UIImage *scaledImage = [image scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(1,self.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledImage];
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        timeLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        CGImageRef ref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(scaledImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 10, 12, 20));
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];  
        timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        self.detailTextLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x808080);
        timeLabel.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x808080);
        timeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}
```

hope this helps some people!